# R Markdown in Weebly Blog

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, blogs, weebly

I can create a `.rmd` file within RStudio but Weebly only allows one to integrate R code.

I'd really like the R code portions of my blog posts to be interactive (Jupyter style) and show the plots, etc.

**Question:**  How can I go about this.

Comment: Do you want to display the markdown? The HTML from that markdown? The raw R? You need to give a **lot** more information before anyone can help you.

Comment: Hi! So basically, I can create a .rmd file within RStudio but Weebly only allows one to integrate R code. I'd really like the R code portions of my blog posts to be interactive (Jupyter style) and show the plots, etc. I'm just not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Did you find resolution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this by creating a custom app with:

- [Weebly Element](https://dev.weebly.com/what-are-elements.html)
- [Weebly Backend Service](https://dev.weebly.com/create-a-backend-service.html) [OPTIONAL]

The element portion of the app would act as a container for the front-end code to load rendered content and necessary display libraries from the backend service portion of the app. You could also just have the element load an `iframe` of the content and allow an external service to handle rendering.

Then in your blog posts you would drag instances of the Element app and configure each instance to retrieve appropriate content from your backend service.

Of course, the backend service portion of the Weebly app is not mandatory, but "some" external service for rendering the R content would be, because the element app can have custom external settings which could be used to load content/settings on a per-instance basis that can be accessed using *external settings* (an external web service) to choose which data to render for display in the element.